# Facebook SDK Unity Publish

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

I'm developing an Android game in which I connect to Facebook. If the user is connected, they can publish the application on their Facebook wall.

The problem that in the script `InteractiveConsole.cs` When the user clicks on the publish button and then the cancel button, I want to show this message: "Not published".
When they click on only the publish button and it is published, I want to show the message :"publish".

The problem is that in both cases, when I decide to either publish or cancel, it shows me the message :"publish" on the GUI.

Here is my code:

```
public GUIText guiFeed;

#region FB.Feed() example

    public string FeedToId = "";
    public string FeedLink = "http://www.google.com";
    public string FeedLinkName = "Test";
    public string FeedLinkCaption = "Test Caption ";
    public string FeedLinkDescription = "Test Deszcription";
    public string FeedPicture = "http://www.selfspark.com/wp-content/uploads/Smiley-Face-Button.jpg";
    public string FeedMediaSource = "";
    public string FeedActionName = "";
    public string FeedActionLink = "";
    public string FeedReference = "";
    public bool IncludeFeedProperties = false;
    private Dictionary<string, string[]> FeedProperties = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();

    public void CallFBFeed()
    {
        Dictionary<string, string[]> feedProperties = null;
        if (IncludeFeedProperties)
        {
            feedProperties = FeedProperties;
        }
        FB.Feed(
            toId: FeedToId,
            link: FeedLink,
            linkName: FeedLinkName,
            linkCaption: FeedLinkCaption,
            linkDescription: FeedLinkDescription,
            picture: FeedPicture,
            mediaSource: FeedMediaSource,
            actionName: FeedActionName,
            actionLink: FeedActionLink,
            reference: FeedReference,
            properties: feedProperties,
            callback: LogCallback
        );
    }


    void LogCallback(FBResult response)
    {
        Debug.Log(response.Text);
        guiFeed.text = "response Feed:"+response.Text;

        if (response.Text == null)
        {
            feedd.text = "not publish";
        }
        else
        {
            feedd.text = " publish";
        }

    }


    #endregion
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When Facebook Share is cancelled, there is a true boolean value for `cancelled` field in response.

First of all, you should parse response JSON from string to a Dictionary, then you should check whether it exists and whether it is positive value, meaning cancelled share.

You should update your code like this:

```
void LogCallback(FBResult response)
{
    var responseObject = Json.Deserialize(response.Text) as Dictionary<string, object>;
    object cancelled;
    if (responseObject.TryGetValue ("cancelled", out cancelled))
    {
        if( (bool)cancelled == true )
        {
            feedd.text = "not publish";
        }
        else
        {
            feedd.text = "publish";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        feedd.text = "publish";
    }
}
```